# In WPF, what associates a ListBoxItem with a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox, custom-controls, listboxitem

This is related to [Issues with alignment with selection in a listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544261/issues-with-alignment-with-selection-in-a-listbox)

I had a go at replacing a ListBox with two custom controls - GridControl and GridItemControl. The problem I'm seeing is there's no connection between the two, i.e. when you add items to GridControl, they're not GridItemControl. I can tell as the mousedown event doesn't fire.

I do see an association if I use XAML to embed a GridItemControl in GridControl but that's not the same as ItemSource.

Here's GridControl:

```
public class GridControl : Selector
{
    static GridControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridControl)));
    }
}
```

Here's GridItemControl:

```
public class GridItemControl : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Bar",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(GridItemControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrackProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Track",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(GridItemControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PickedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Picked",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(GridItemControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public int Bar
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(BarProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(BarProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int Track
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.GetValue(TrackProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TrackProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public bool Picked
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(PickedProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(PickedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    static GridItemControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(GridItemControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridItemControl)));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            this.Picked = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PatternControlLibrary"
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<system:Double x:Key="barWidth">30</system:Double>
<system:Double x:Key="trackHeight">24</system:Double>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:GridControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:GridControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:GridPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" BarWidth="{StaticResource barWidth}" TrackHeight="{StaticResource trackHeight}">
                    <local:GridPanel.Background>
                        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                            <DrawingBrush.Viewbox>
                                <Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="{StaticResource barWidth}" Height="{StaticResource trackHeight}"/>
                            </DrawingBrush.Viewbox>
                            <DrawingBrush.Viewport>
                                <Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="{StaticResource barWidth}" Height="{StaticResource trackHeight}"/>
                            </DrawingBrush.Viewport>
                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="LightGray">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="1"/>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <PathGeometry>
                                            <PathFigure IsFilled="True">
                                                <LineSegment>
                                                    <LineSegment.Point>
                                                        <Point X="{StaticResource barWidth}" Y="0"/>
                                                    </LineSegment.Point>
                                                </LineSegment>
                                                <LineSegment>
                                                    <LineSegment.Point>
                                                        <Point X="{StaticResource barWidth}" Y="{StaticResource trackHeight}"/>
                                                    </LineSegment.Point>
                                                </LineSegment>
                                                <LineSegment>
                                                    <LineSegment.Point>
                                                        <Point X="0" Y="{StaticResource trackHeight}"/>
                                                    </LineSegment.Point>
                                                </LineSegment>
                                                <LineSegment/>
                                            </PathFigure>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </local:GridPanel.Background>
                </local:GridPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:GridItemControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:GridItemControl}">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="local:GridPanel.Bar" Value="{Binding Bar}"/>
    <Setter Property="local:GridPanel.Track" Value="{Binding Track}"/>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I use the following in MainWindow.xaml I get what I'd expect:

```
<Grid>
    <cc:GridControl 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataItemTemplate}">
        <cc:GridItemControl Content="Test" Bar="5" Track="3"/>
    </cc:GridControl>
</Grid>
```

(apart from the box isn't aligned according to Bar and Track, but that's another issue!).

If I replace this with what I'd expect to use:

```
<Grid>
    <cc:GridControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataItemTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

then GridItemControl isn't used, as I don't see the mousedown event when I click on a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement a custom `ItemsControl` and want to use a custom container type, there are some methods you will need to override:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new GridItemControl();
}

protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return (item is GridItemControl);
}
```

The methods above are how an `ItemsControl` generates container elements for the underlying data items.  `ListBox`, for example, overrides these to provide `ListBoxItem` containers instead of the standard `ContentControl`.

Also, if you want to stick to the accepted naming conventions, `GridItemControl` should really be called `GridControlItem`.